# PHP MYSQL Return last 3 months from a date from the DB - Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an PHP/MySQL application. I am struk with something. For example:

MySQL Table is as follows:

```
id   |  deadline_date | reminder1   | reminder2 | reminder3
______________________________________________________________

 1       2021-04-26
```

In my above table deadline_date is 2021-04-26. Then first reminder (reminder1) will be sent on 2021-02-25, the second reminder (reminder2) will be sent on 2021-03-25, and third reminder (reminder3) will be sent on 2021-04-25. So from the deadline_date these 3 reminders have to be calculated and updated on the particular fields (reminder1, reminder2 and reminder3). So the table has to be populated with the following data:

```
id   |  deadline_date | reminder1   | reminder2 | reminder3
______________________________________________________________

 1       2021-04-26     2021-02-25    2021-03-25   2021-04-25
```

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this? i am not sure if i can achieve this from a MYSQL Query UPDATE query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Interval for that purpose

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `deadline_date` DATE,
>   `reminder1` DATE,
>   `reminder2` DATE,
>   `reminder3` DATE
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `deadline_date`, `reminder1`, `reminder2`, `reminder3`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2021-04-26', NULL, NULL, NULL);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1 t1
> SET t1.`reminder1` = t1.`deadline_date`  - INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH,
> t1.`reminder2` = t1.`deadline_date`  - INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,
> t1.`reminder3` = t1.`deadline_date`  - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | deadline_date | reminder1  | reminder2  | reminder3 
> -: | :------------ | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
>  1 | 2021-04-26    | 2021-02-25 | 2021-03-25 | 2021-04-25
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ec569f2914097f5116bbcd934cb371fe)*

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET reminder3=DATE_ADD(deadline_date, INTERVAL -1 day),
reminder2=DATEA_ADD(DATE_ADD(deadline_date, INTERVAL -1 day), INTERVAL -1 MONTH),
reminder1=DATEA_ADD(DATE_ADD(deadline_date, INTERVAL -1 day), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)
```

Comment: Thank you, its fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATE_ADD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp) function to set the remainders:

```
UPDATE mytable 
   set reminder1 = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(deadline_date, INTERVAL -2 MONTH), INTERVAL -1 DAY),
   reminder2 = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(deadline_date, INTERVAL -1 MONTH), INTERVAL -1 DAY), 
   reminder3 = DATE_ADD(deadline_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```